# Flatlist onVIewableItemsChanged prop is not being called when FlatList re renders in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using flatlist where there is a prop named onViewableItemChanged which needs to be called every time flatlist re renders. But even though flatlist data changes as a result flatlist updates but onViewableItemsChanged props is called only when new row added in viewable area (i.e initially 6 row then added one new row, then it will be called) or user interacts i.e scroll through the list.

But if there is 20 row and data updates in row 1 it would not being called.

Is there any workaround to resolve this issue.?
Thanx in advance.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cardData: [{name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
        {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'}]
      }

    this.handleViewableItemsChanged = this.handleViewableItemsChanged.bind(this)
    this.viewabilityConfig = {viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50}
}

handleViewableItemsChanged(info) {
  console.log(info)
  console.log("potato")
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
              title="Some State Change Button"
              onPress={()=>
                this.setState({
                  cardData: [{name: 'Clean Up the FOREST'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},{name:'true'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'},
                  {name: 'Clean Up the Oceans'}, {name: 'three'}
                ]})
              }
            />
            <FlatList
                ref='FlatList'
                data={this.state.cardData}
                extraData={this.state.cardData}
                horizontal={false}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
                viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}

                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <View style={{width: width, borderColor: 'white', borderWidth: 20,backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        <Text>Hello World</Text>
                    </View>
                }
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: onViewableItemChanged is for checking viewable items in your ViewPort, I think you want to check data change in each row?

Comment: yes ..want to check data change in row.

Comment: onViewableItemChanged is not for checking data in rows, what you need to do is check previous state with new state and then do something on the basis of change.

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you change data or rerender flatlist.

just use Ref:

```
const handleViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }) => { //todo });
.
.
.
<FlatList
  ...
  onViewableItemsChanged={handleViewableItemsChanged.current}
  ...
/>
```